# Different DOM structures with equivalent code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As far as I know, the two following snippets should be equivalent. Both create some variables, add a `svg` element, append a `group` element, and append a second `group`.

Case 1:

```
var margin = {top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 50, right: 50},
    height = 350,
    width = 800;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
```

Case 2:

```
var margin = {top: 15, bottom: 15, left: 50, right: 50},
    height = 350,
    width = 800;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
```

However, in the first case, the second `group` element is a child of the first `group`, i.e. the DOM has the following structure:

```
<svg height="380" width="900">
    <g transform="translate(50,15)">
        <g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,350)">
```

And in the second case, both `group`s are child of the `svg` element:

```
<svg height="380" width="900">
    <g transform="translate(50,15)">
    <g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,350)">
```

Comment: In the first case, the variable `svg` points to the first `g` element, in the second to the `svg` element.

Comment: So, it is not equivalent chaining methods that break the code in different lines?

Comment: Well `.append()` returns the selection it appended. So the result will be whatever the last `.append()` did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you get back the appended group in the svg variable. It is a common problem I encountered it several times.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .append("g")  // you get this object back
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```